# React Native How do I add an object in an array using the map?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

this is my array

```
var arr1 = [{key:0, ele: "A"}, {key:1, ele: "B"}]
```

i want to make a new array with arr1 using **map**

like this

```
newarray = [
 {
  title: "@@@", items: [{here: "A"}, {here: "B"}]
 }
]
```

In summary, I want to put the `ele` of `arr1` in `here` of `newarray[0].items`. And I hope `newarray[0].title` is maintained.

Thank you for your time and I look forward to your advice.

Comment: `newarray[0] = { title: '@@@', items: arr1.map(v => ({ here: v.ele }) ) }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
newarray = [
 {
  title: "@@@", items: arr1.map(element => {here:element.ele})
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this,If you find any issues feel free to ask

```
var arr1 = [{key:0, ele: "A"}, {key:1, ele: "B"}]
var newarray = [
 {
  title: "@@@", items: arr1.map(el => {return ({here:el.ele})})
 }
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was very helpful. But I could only adopt one, so I adopted a friend who gave me a faster answer. I hope you don't feel bad. Once again, thank you very much!

Comment: No problem.I hope this was helpful for you.if you find this useful please like it.